# How to include verbatim source code into an html document

Tags: javascript, html, reveal.js

I've written several C++ programs that live in the same repository as a reveal.js presentation. What I would like to do is to simply include the C++ source file into my document.

First, I found a great way to include a file into an html document using the following function (thanks to stackoverflow):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#awesomecpp").load("../src/awesome.cpp");
});
</script>
```

Then I include it in my reveal.js presentation like this:

```
<pre><code data-trim>
<div id="awesomecpp"></div>
</code></pre>
```

However, this is no bueno because I end up with `<div id="awesomecpp>` at the top of the source code, plus a bunch of other junk tags at the end of the source code snippet. I'd very much not like to have to copy and paste code because I find I make changes frequently to the code, and will probably not make changes to the presentation code. Furthermore, I found that if there are any special characters such as '&', bad things will also happen. Does anyone have any suggestions for use of a javascript library that can handle what I want to do properly? I simply want to include a file verbatim with code formatting into my reveal.js presentation. Is that too much to ask?

Comment: It's not possible to embed c++ via javascript

Comment: Not trying to "embed" it, just want to display the actual c++ verbatim (or any language for that matter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url : "../src/awesome.cpp",
  dataType: "text",
  success : function (data) {
    $("#awesomecpp").text(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Would be best to set the `text` property probably as opposed to html as html may cause characters such as < and > to be interpretted as HTML tags causing issues

Comment: "It's not possible to embed c++ via javascript" and then 4 minutes later you post on how to do it.  Well played!  +1

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that reveal.js uses the highlight.js for syntax highlighting and that will use the contents of the `code` tag (*your `div` in this case*).

You most likely need to put the id on the `code` tag.

```
<pre><code data-trim id="awesomecpp">
</code></pre>
```

You might also have to prevent the reveal.js from initializing the syntax highlighter when it does and manually run it after the ajax is loaded.

Comment: This almost works but it still processes "<>" as tags which is not good. I have a lot of template parameters in my C++ code this creates a lot of chaos once rendered to html.